# Mathematica is messing around with absolute values and sqrts of complex numbers?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, output-formatting, complex, formatting, rule

I know that $$\begin{pmatrix}0&Z\\Z^*&0\end{pmatrix} \quad\text{has eigenvalues}\quad \lambda_\pm=\pm|Z|$$

but Mathematica gives me

```
Eigenvalues@{{0,z},{Conjugate[z],0}}
(* { -Sqrt[z]Sqrt[Conjugate[z]], Sqrt[z]Sqrt[Conjugate[z]] } *)
```

I think this is not right because we have $\,\sqrt{ZZ^*}\neq\sqrt{Z}\sqrt{Z^*}$.

e.g. For $Z=-1$ we have $\sqrt{1}\neq (\sqrt{-1})^2\,$.

So, given this, I wonder if there is a way to solve this and output the result as $\pm|Z|$, even for the cases where instead of Z we had a product, or a sum of products.

Comment: I get that `z0 = -1.;
Sort@Eigenvalues[{{0, z}, {Conjugate[z], 0}} /. z -> z0] ==
 Sort@(Eigenvalues@{{0, z}, {Conjugate[z], 0}} /. z -> z0)` returns `True`. Is it the case that $\pm\,\sqrt{ZZ^*}=\pm\sqrt{Z}\sqrt{Z^*}$ in some order?

Comment: @MichaelE2:  I think you're onto something. With `mat` defined as the matrix above, `Eigenvalues@(mat /. z -> -1)` gives `{-1,1}` while `(Eigenvalues@mat) /. z -> -1` gives `{1, -1}`.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I think the two expressions differ by a factor of `E^((1/2)*I*(Arg[z] + Arg[Conjugate[z]]))` and `Arg[z] + Arg[Conjugate[z]]` is either `0` or `2 Pi`. Thus the factor is $\pm1$.

Comment: `m = {{0, x + I y}, {x - I y, 0}};
Eigenvalues[m]`

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this?

```
Eigenvalues[
 ComplexExpand[{{0, z}, {Conjugate[z], 0}},
  z, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}]]

(*  {-Abs[z], Abs[z]}  *)
```